# Rails Time.now.in_time_zone issue with -1200 zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, activesupport

We allow users to pass in their time offset when using our app.  Some are passing in -1200 which is raising an error of Invalid TimeZone... It's not finding that UTC offset, but in digging a bit, I feel like it should be finding it. According to wikipedia, an offset of -12 is valid:

United States Minor Outlying Islands
Baker Island
Howland Island

What's the deal with Rail's zone handling with this offset?

Comment: http://www.statoids.com/tum.html
Of these islands, only Johnston, Midway, and Wake have permanent residents at present. The others are visited at intervals, mostly by the military.
Hence the absence perhaps?

Comment: Must be so obscure that it's not supported... Still kinda weird.  We get a decent amount of people using the app with that TZ reported.  Will hack to use -1100 if recognized for now.

Comment: Its quite interesting you say that. I think this one should be raised as an issue then https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Comment: It certainly gets confused around that time zone:  `Time.now.in_time_zone('Etc/GMT-12')` => `Wed, 28 May 2014 07:04:09 GMT-12 +12:00` (UTC is currently `Tue, 27 May 2014 19:04:09 UTC +00:00`)

Answer (score 2):

Upon more exploring:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11390

If you really need a zone with a UTC -12:00 offset you can use the Etc/GMT+12 zone, odd yes  its moved to other side of the date line but is shown as GMT+12 -12:00 which are the same.

```
>> ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING['Baker Island'] = 'Etc/GMT+12'
"Etc/GMT+12"

>> Time.zone = 'Baker Island'
"Baker Island"

>> Time.current
Tue, 27 May 2014 18:28:48 GMT+12 -12:00
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Good answer.  But, it's not moved to the other side of the date line.  It's just that zones in the `Etc` area have the sign inverted in their name for backwards compliance with POSIX time zones.  See the third paragraph under "Area" in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Names_of_time_zones).